# Bar constructions and pushouts

Tags: ct.category-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, homological-algebra, homology, associative-algebras

Suppose that $\mathsf S$ is a span of associative algebras (or, more generally, if you'd like, any type of object admitting a bar-cobar formalism) and let $A$ be its pushout.

> Is there any hope of obtaining information about $BA$ in terms of the diagram of bar constructions $B(\mathsf S)$?

I fear little can be said in general, but would be happy to be proven wrong. If this is the case, does anyone have a good non-example?

Comment: I have a bit of trouble parsing the question. Do you mean "information from $BA$" or "information about $BA$"?

Comment: Perhaps the accepted answer in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/645972/mayer-vietoris-type-sequence-for-pushouts (about a different category) sheds light on some of the problems arising.

Comment: @VladimirDotsenko I meant information *about* $BA$. I have edited the question.

Comment: @VladimirDotsenko Right, that behaviour in $\mathsf{Top}$ is what motivates me to be pessimistic. From an algebraic point of view, taking pushouts means some "inert" relations in one algebra can start interacting with some other "inert" relations in the other one, ruining good homotopical properties. For example, one can easily construct a span of Koszul algebras whose pushout is not Koszul.

Comment: since for Koszul spaces the algebraic bar construction converts the algebra $H^*(X)$ into (a model of) the coalgebra $H^*(\Omega X)$,  I am suspecting that topological pathologies can be easily converted into algebraic ones, no?

Comment: I know if you take the pushout of two monoids along a common submonoid then the corresponding pushout of classifying spaces is not necessarily homotopy equivalent to the classifying space of the monoid pushout unless the submonoid sits very nicely inside the two factors.  This makes it seem unlikely that in full generality the bar resolutions behave nicely.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg Can you expand on what "sits very nicely" means? In my situation associative algebras are not that far from monoids, so I'd be curious to know what this condition is.

Comment: The literature is a bit messy on this. There are some incorrect results that say a flatness is enough.  What definitely works is if N is a submonoid of M,M’ such that N acts freely on the left or right of both M,M’ then the classifying space of the pushing is the pushout of classifying spaces

Comment: It was claimed in one paper that ZM and ZM’ just need to be flat over ZN but the argument in the paper seemed spurious to me and someone on MO found a counterexample to what the paper asserted. 

I think it is enough if I recall for Z(M*_N M’) to be flat over ZN but you don’t get this from each of ZM and ZN-flat.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg is there a reference for the result under the assumption of freeness?

Comment: It's in Dusa Mcduff's paper where she shows every connected CW complex is homotopy equivalent to the classifying space of a monoid

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg many thanks! If anyone else is wondering, this is the link to the paper : https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0040938379900223

Comment: Incidentally, in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1908.11283.pdf) Chuang and Lazarev show (Corollary 2.3) that the homotopy pushout of dg-algebras coincides with the usual pushout provided the maps are cofibrations of left modules. This is in good concordance with the paper above.